# Understanding AC_errorRate loss function

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression, statistics, loss-function

I'm reading an article about [Rolling Window Regression: a Simple Approach for Time Series Next value Predictions](https://medium.com/making-sense-of-data/time-series-next-value-prediction-using-regression-over-a-rolling-window-228f0acae363).

He explains about 5 different loss functions. I managed to understand the first four, but I don't understand the fifth one:

> 5. Almost correct Predictions Error rate (AC_errorRate) — the percentage of predictions that is within %p percentage of the true
>      value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, this loss type means:

- you define a threshold percentage error (let’s say 2%)
- for each true value y, the desired prediction should be between `y + 0.02*y` and `y - 0.02*y`
- the percentage of predicted values fulfilling the rule above contribute to the “inliers” predictions, I.e., good predictions

This idea reminds me to what [RANSAC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RANSACRegressor.html) does